# Adding class to tr with nested divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to add classes to tr .inside the table with class name .flexme1

I tried the various options below but didnt seem to work..

```
  //jQuery("div.flexigrid > table.flexme1 > tr").addClass("cal");

or

        jQuery("div.flexigrid > table.flexme1 > tr").addClass("sev1");
  or 
        jQuery(".erow").addClass("sev2");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid > tr").addClass("sev3");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid >tr").addClass("sev4");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid >tr").addClass("sev5");
```

I would like the tr to have the class="somename" added to it.

```
<div class="flexigrid">
  ..< some other divs>...<<table> ..</table></div>
... <some other divs>...<table>..</table></div>
---
<div class="bDiv" >
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="flexme1" >
      <tbody>
         <tr  class="sev1">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow"  class="sev1">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">1</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr   class="sev3">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">1</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">BM1M</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">4</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">BM1N</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="iDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>


</div><!-- end of div>
```

Comment: Try this ```jQuery(".flexme1 tr").addClass("inside");```

Comment: It would help if you'd reduce your HTML to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You posted this yesterday and a bunch of us gave you solutions. Don't post another question about it asking the exact same thing. Changing the classes used wasn't going to go over our heads...

Comment: Cleaned up the code  and the solution didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

you're almost right, just [remove the `>`](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) - the `table` is not a [direct child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) of `.flexigrid` as there is another `div.bDiv` between them:

```
jQuery("div.flexigrid table.flexme1 tr").addClass("somename");
```

Comment: @oeszi - thank you i tried that but didnt seem to add the class i also tried this way jQuery("div.flexigrid table.flexme1 tr td").addClass("somename"); and jQuery("div.flexigrid table.flexme1 tbody tr td").addClass("somename");

Answer (score 1):

Just do this way:-

```
jQuery(".bDiv table.flexme1 tr").addClass("inside");
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/4DdUW/)**

Comment: @Chivan - thank you.. I tried that too it didnt seem to take it, I also noticedthat using  jQuery(".bDiv table.flexme1 ").addClass("inside"); seem to  add the class up in table but doesnt seem to add it to the tr. not sure why it wont add to teh trs

Comment: @user244394: I guess, something you are doing wrong. Can you show us a demo how it is not adding the class?